# SVG path animation using jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, html, svg, jquery-svg

I have created the HTML 5 SVG line chart through jquery. Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

Please refer the below SVG path:

```
<path id="John" clip-path="url(&quot;#ChartAreaClip&quot;)" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" d="M 136 213.6 L 202 259.36 M 202 259.36 L 268 222.18 M 268 222.18 L 334 159.26 M 334 159.26 L 400 150.68 M 400 150.68 L 466 79.18 M 466 79.18 L 532 170.7 M 532 170.7 L 598 167.84 M 598 167.84 L 664 99.2"/>
```

i want to perform the path animation  (i.e.) line to be draw like motion effect. like below link

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

i have referred the below links but cant get idea.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/animateMotion

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/animateColor

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/animate

can you please provide any solution to make animated path for line chart ? (i.e) path animation for line chart

Thanks,

siva

Answer (score 0):

For this effect you could define a rectangular clipPath, animate that rectangle, and use it for the clip-path of the path.

Like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="curtainClip">
            <rect id="clipRect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <animate xlink:href="#clipRect"
        attributeName="width" 
        dur="1s"
        from="0" 
        to="100" />

    <path clip-path="url(#curtainClip)" stroke="red" d="M 0 0 L 100 100"/>
</svg>
```